# clases en javascript

Tags: javascript, html

tengo una tabla dinamica que al cambiar el pais en un select me debe listar las emisoras asociadas a ese pais, la tabla se muestra a traves de un codigo javascript

```
$('#filtrarPais').on('change', function(){
            contenido.innerHTML = ''
            var pais = $('#filtrarPais').val()
            filtrarEmisoras(pais)
        })

        function filtrarEmisoras(pais){
            //console.log(pais)
            fetch('PAIS/'+pais+'/EMISORAS.json')
            .then(emisora => emisora.json())
            .then(datosEmisora =>{
                tabla(datosEmisora)
            })

        }

        function tabla(datosEmisora){
            for (let valor of datosEmisora) {
                contenido.innerHTML += `
                    <tr>
                        <td class="checkbox" width="50px" align="center"><input type="checkbox"class="checkbox" width="50px"></td>
                        <td class="cel-pais" width="150px">${valor.pais}</td>
                        <td class="cel-emisora">${valor.emisora}</td>
                        <td class="cel-id">${valor.id}</td>
                        <td class="cel-url">${valor.url}</td>
                        <td class="cel-web">${valor.web}</p></td>
                        <td>    
                            <a class="editar-emisora" href="#"> EDITAR </a>
                            / 
                            <a class="eliminar-emisora" href="#"> ELIMINAR </a>
                            /
                            <a href="${valor.web}" target="_blank"> VER </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>   
                `
            }
        }
```

el problema esta en el ultimo td el cual contiene las acciones de editar, eliminar y ver, dentro del codigo de javascript no se ejecutan las funciones cuando se le da click

hay alguna forma de a esos links darle la funcion normal dentro del codigo de javascript?

Comment: no funciona, de iagual manera los botones creados desde javascript al darle click no hacen nada

Comment: En editar que quieres hacer ? abrir otra ventana con el registro o agregar elementos textbox en los campos editables? aqui un ejemplo de lo ultimo https://codepen.io/eirenaios/pen/VbZagL